# jQuery functions not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wrote the following JavaScript code for saving a document:

```
function save()
{
$.prompt('Are you sure you want to save changes to this document?',{
  callback: savechanges,
  buttons: { Yes: 'Yes', No: 'No' }
});
function savechanges(v,m){
 document.write('Date hello: ', page);
  if(v=="Yes")
  {
    var content = $('#content').val();// This line is not running
    var page = trim($('#pageid').val()); // This line is not running
    content = escape(content);
    $.post("../gamescripts/save.php",
    {  page: page, content: content },
    function(data){
    if(trim(data)=="success")
        {
       document.location = page ;                                   
        }
    }); 
  }
}
}
```

But the following two jQuery lines are unable to extract the data from content and page id: But, they are not generating any errors

```
    var content = $('#content').val();
    var page = trim($('#pageid').val());
```

This is the `php` file which calls the JavaScript function. I have included the `jquery.js` library. Do I need to include any other library?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../gamejavascripts/jquery.js"></script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="javascript:save();">

<input name="pageid"  type="text" id="pageid"  value="<?php echo "$url"?>" READONLY/>
<textarea name="content" id= "content" cols="80" rows="18">";
<?php
$handle = fopen("$url","r");
 while(!feof($handle))
 { 
 $text = fgets($handle);
echo $text;
}
fclose($handle);
?>
</textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Save"  />

</form>
```

This is the save.php file

```
<?php

$content= $_POST["content"];
$page= trim($_POST["pageid"]);
$text = rawurldecode($content);



$myFile = $page;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

$status= "success";

fwrite($fh, $text);
fclose($fh);

echo $status;



?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not running"? What else is running? It would help if you could show a minimal example which works.

Comment: "This is the php which calls the javascript function", okay you got me, my head is hurting now.  Can you explain what and how the code is supposed to work?

Comment: As Michael said, adding more precise description on the specific problem (or the parts that are not working as expected) helps on focusing the answers on those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are looking for `jQuery` trim function then use `$.trim()`.

```
var page = $.trim($('#pageid').val());//It will work now
```

You should not get any error in the below line though

```
var content = $('#content').val();
```

Comment: It;'s working now. thanks a lot ! But the javscript functions is unable to open the file. Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: You have used `trim` in the success hanlder also ` if(trim(data)=="success")` change there as well. If everything goes well it should work fine.

Comment: I have made the change. It's still unable to open the file . i think the error is in save.php which I have pasted just now. Is the opening mode correct?